# change the background of a text When mousemove

Tags: jquery

How to change the background of a text When mousemove using jquery/Js?

I need text highlighting for each character when the mouse is moved, not for the entire div and I want the previous mouse over event should also be highlighted.

I am trying this on iphone safari browser. touchmove event is calling once not continuously.

Comment: Please be more specific. Details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yCPZr/) more what you're looking for?

Comment: no, i want the previous mouse over event should also be highlighted.

Comment: Bryan, Thanks, it was working fine in browser when i changed the mouseenter into touchmove and trying this in device, it was not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#MyElementID").mouseover(function() { $(this).attr("background-color", "red");  } );
```

I think the above is about right.

or use something like from the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) site;

```
$("#MyElementID").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

Comment: The first example should be `$(this).css("background-color","red");`. Note the `css()` call instead of the `attr()` call.

Comment: Hi Bryan Ross, thanks, but i need text highlighting for each character when the mouse is moved, not for the entire div.

Comment: @user440367 maybe you want to be more specific in your question as this is not clear.

Comment: hi griegs, for eg there is a <p>Lorem ipsum</p> When i move the mouse over the characters. it should be highlighted with any bg-color.

Comment: Are you saying as the mouse moves across a character, you want to be able to change the background color of that specific character?

Comment: yes, i want to change the background color of specific character